# Is It Safe to Install .NET Framework 4.5 on Windows Server 2008 Running .NET Framework 2.0?

Tags: .net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, .net-framework-version

I currently am running an ASP.NET MVC2 web application on my Windows 2008 R2 server and I'd like to upgrade my application to MVC4.  This will of course require the installation of the later .NET Framework onto the server.  Will the server be able to handle both versions of the .NET Framework, and will IIS 7.0 be able to handle the later version of .NET framework?

Will it be possible to run some websites using MVC2 and the earlier .NET Framework alongside some MCV4 apps in the same IIS instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the .NET Framework supports side by side execution which means that installing multiple version shouldn't effect each other.

For all details and explanation how an application *chooses* his version see: [Side-by-Side Execution in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8477k21c.aspx)

Comment: Don't be misled though. 2.0 and 4.5 are side-by-side, but if you have .Net 4.0, and then install 4.5, it's an in-place upgrade(4.0 assemblies will point to 4.5 assemblies). It'd be unlikely to break applications, but it is possible for it to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can install any and all .NET Framework Versions side-by-side.

***This next may not be necessary, but it doesn't hurt:***

I've had better success installing them in order.  First 2.0, then 3.0, then 4.5, then 4.0.  ***Again, This should not be necessary***, but I've had some goofy errors when installing them our of order that were fixed by uninstalling them and then re-installing them in the right order.  That may only apply  to 2.0 - 3.5, though because 3.0 and 3.5 were additive installations - they merely added to version 2.0.  4.0 is more of a "true" different version.